# How to avoid overlapping of labels in timeline plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[image: center labels overlap]Hey everyone, i use the plot example from https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/timeline.html
Code is similar from the example there. Just some different values for the list names and dates.

Now i have got the problem, as shown in the picture below that some of the labels overlap.
How can I avoid that?
It is not the only plot of that kind i will make so it would be great to find a way that it works for any data input.

I already adjusted the space between the x-axis elements but I do not know how to fix that problem with the labels.

Comment: seems like the whole example is not deterministic at all. I run it several times and the labels seem to appear at different places after each execution

Comment: The example you quote is deterministic in the sense that it always cycles the lineheight through `[-5, 5, -3, 3, -1, 1]`. Of course if you change the total number of lines, it will give a different result. If you make sure the data you loop over is sorted chronologically, the sequence `[-5, 5, -3, 3, -1, 1]` should avoid direct overlaps, but of course you may also adjust that sequence with more levels. You do not show any code [mcve], so that's about all one can say here.

Comment: thanks for the reply @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Thanks for the hints with the levels. But still, when i run my code with the same data (no change of amount of lines) it gives out different plots. Sorry for not posting my code, i thought it would be enough with the link, as my data is quite the same. (dates and some strings as labels), so..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution thanks to the reply of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. My 2 input lists where not sorted by date.